# python 3.6 changing a list to a 2 digit then a space

Tags: python

I have saw this and this works on the shell but I need a way where it will work on the python editor can anyone help

```
a = '345674655'
[a[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(a), 3)]
```

and outputs

```
['345', '674', '655']
```

This is what I want but so I can do it not on the shell on  print

how do I get this to work I do know how it works just can't get it too?

```
a = '345674655'
ar = [a[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(a), 3)]
print(*ar)

str2= " | ".join(ar(e) for e in ar)
print (str2)
```

Comment: just print your result...

Comment: Where are there two digits and then a space? Why does your name have to be below your post twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
a = '345674655'
ar = [a[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(a), 3)]
print(*ar)
```

Output:

```
345 674 655
```

**Updated:**
Second Update: No need to use *list comprehension* in this case as @Darthfett's comment.

```
a = '345674655'
ar = [a[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(a), 3)]
print(*ar)

str2= " | ".join(ar)
print (str2)
```

Updated Output:

```
345 674 655
345 | 674 | 655
```

Comment: Probably just `print(ar)`

Comment: @JonDeaton how OP came up with complex slicing listcomp and isn't able to print it? it's like inventing the can of soup, and not the can opener ...

Comment: I'm not sure tbh, maybe hes just confused about why the interpreter automatically prints stuff out whereas running a program doesn't? I remember being confused about that once haha

Comment: ```print(ar)``` will print it as array and ```print(*ar)``` will unpacks the list and return every element in the list. What is the reason of down vote?

Comment: @AdamMartin, glad to hear. If it so, mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: I understand what OP wants now, but it's wasn't clear before editing. now it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46119144/printing-variable-that-contains-string-and-2-other-variables

Comment: hi how do I mark it sorry and also one more question ill add it into main post

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from grayed out to filled in. Thank you.

Comment: I've edited please can you see if you can help? cheers arsho

Comment: @AdamMartin, updated my answer. It is good to see you playing with alternative solutions. Happy coding!

Comment: The list comprehension `[e for e in ar]` is redundant.  Why not just `str2 = ' | '.join(ar)`?

Comment: thank you arsho also thanks for the quick reply with a answer!

Comment: @Darthfett, you are absolutely right. thanks. updated the answer.